# Dynamic wildcard subdomain ingress for Kubernetes

Tags: networking, kubernetes, load-balancing, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm currently using Kubernetes on GKE to serve the various parts of my product on different subdomains with the Ingress resource. For example: `api.mydomain.com`, `console.mydomain.com`, etc.

**ingress.yml (current)**:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - host: api.mydomain.com
    http:
      paths:
        - backend:
            serviceName: api-service
            servicePort: 80
  - host: console.mydomain.com
    http:
      paths:
        - backend:
            serviceName: console-service
            servicePort: 80
```

That works wonderfully, with the L7 GCE load balancer routing to the appropriate places. What I would like to do, however, is deploy many feature-branch deployments as subdomains to test and demonstrate new features before pushing to production. These could be something like `new-stylesheet.console.mydomain.com` or `upgraded-algorithm.api.mydomain.com`, inspired by GitLab CI's [environments](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/environments.html).

Here's a potential workflow for each deployment:

1. Create feature-api-deployment.yml
2. Create feature-api-service.yml
3. Update ingress.yml with new subdomain rule: `feature.api.mydomain.com` specifying `serviceName: feature-api-service`

But enumerating and maintaining all subdomain->service mappings will get messy with tearing down deployments, and create a ton of GCE backends (default quota is 5...) so it's not ideal.

Is there anything built in to Kubernetes that I'm overlooking to handle this? Something like this would be ideal to pick a target service based on a matched subdomain:

**ingress.yml (wanted)**

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - host: *.api.mydomain.com
    http:
      paths:
        - backend:
            serviceName: {value of *}-api-service
            servicePort: 80
```

Comment: Did you able to implement the needed automated solution? If yes, would you be so kind to share some specifics?

Comment: @AngelTodorov development priorities ended up shifting and this particular project fell off the radar. Best bet is to follow the advice in the accepted answer. I'll update this question if I get around to actually implementing the answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There certainly isn't anything like wildcard domains available in kubernetes, but you might be able to get want you want using [Helm](http://helm.sh/)

With helm, you can template variables inside your manifests, so you can have the name of your branch be in the helm [values file](https://github.com/kubernetes/helm/blob/master/docs/chart_template_guide/values_files.md)

From there, you can have gitlab-ci do the helm installation in a build pipeline and if you configure your chart correctly, you can specify a helm argument of the pipeline name.

There's a great blog post about this kind of workflow [here](http://blog.lwolf.org/post/how-to-create-ci-cd-pipeline-with-autodeploy-k8s-gitlab-helm/) - hopefully this'll get your where you need to go.

Comment: would you be so kind and provide a sample solution based on your suggestions above?

Comment: @Angel Todorov did you end up coming up with a solution to this?

Comment: Not actually, in fact I have abandoned the topic quite long time ago...

Answer (score 0):

here is an example:

```
 apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
    kind: Ingress
    metadata:
      name: ingress-wildcard-host
    spec:
      rules:
      - host: "foo.bar.com"
        http:
          paths:
          - pathType: Prefix
            path: "/bar"
            backend:
              service:
                name: service1
                port:
                  number: 80
      - host: "*.foo.com"
        http:
          paths:
          - pathType: Prefix
            path: "/foo"
            backend:
              service:
                name: service2
                port:
                  number: 80
```

and the [source](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/).

Comment: the question was about subdomains (`api.*` not `*.example.com`), I believe it's not supported by default ingress

Comment: @MuayyadAlsadi I don't think you're interpreting the OP correctly. It is about routing `x.foo.com` to a service named `x-service`, where `x` is anything. So if I put in `bar.foo.com` I go to `bar-service` and if I go to `bottle.foo.com` it goes to `bottle-service`. I still think this is unsupported, but it's different than a routing of `api.*.foo.com`.

Comment: yes, me and the op and you are talking the same thing,  `x.example.com` goes to service `x` so something binds to `*.example.com` then routes based on subdomain   @nathaniel-ford

Answer (score -2):

Services are available locally as

```
my-svc.svc.cluster.local
```

You can write a simple NGINX proxy which can forward which can parse the subdomain and proxy pass it to http://$service as long as the subdomain and service name matches as in this case.

Comment: Could you provide a simple implementation example on the suggested approach?